# create dummy windows server with started status

Tags: windows, service, exe, service-control-manager

I have created a dummy windows service using the following command:

sc create TestService binPath= C:\Temp\TestService.exe DisplayName= "TestService " start= auto

It successfully created a dummy service in services.msc but I would also need it to show a 'Started' status. I know this will require a bit of coding and my TestService.exe is blank.

Any idea how? I searched thru the net and it requires MS Visual Studio 2010 etc. Looks too complicated, all I need is a blank service that shows a 'Started' status that will be used for testing purpose.

Answer (score 19):

1. Create a dummy.bat file in C:\ with contents "pause"
2. Download NSSM from http://www.nssm.cc/download
3. Extract nssm.exe (x86 or x64) to C:\Windows\nssm.exe
4. Run "nssm install"
5. Path: C:\dummy.bat
6. Service name - As you wish!
7. Hit "Install service"

After that, you'll have a service named after step 6, which you can start, stop, restart...

Hope it helps!

Comment: I just needed to create a dummy service with a specific name and have it started, otherwise a certain software wouldn't uninstall itself (luckily, the uninstaller only checked for the service name and didn't actually interact with the service in any way). This really helped.